# Definition for self-commutated switches

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, circuit-design, circuit-theory

PSIM (an electronic circuit simulation software package) classifies `GTO, IGBT, MOSFET` as `self-commutated switches`. However, I couldn't find a clear definition of this.

This is from [PSIM manual](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=5790b64848954cd897766fdb&assetKey=AS%3A386254429540352%401469101640146):

> **Switches**
>
> There are four basic types of switches in PSIM:
>
> - Diodes (DIODE)
> - Thyristors (THY)
> - Self-commutated switches (GTO, IGBT, MOSFET)
>
> Bi-directional switches (SSWI) Switch models are ideal. That is, both
>   turn-on and turn-off transients are neglected. A switch has an
>   on-resistance of 10µΩ and an off-resistance of 1MΩ. Snubber circuits
>   are not required for switches.

Here is the only definition that I found:

**[Self-Commutated Switches](http://energyprofessionalsymposium.com/?p=35164)**

> The devices of the third category are denoted as self-commutated
>   semiconductor switches. The general properties of devices in this
>   class are the capability of being turned-on or turned-off at will by
>   use of some form of low power (either voltage or current controlled)
>   signal into a third (gate or base) terminal, and normally they have a
>   capability of controlling current only in forward direction. Examples
>   are BJTs, MOSFETs, IGBTs (insulated-gate-bipolar transistors), and
>   many others.

So is `"arbitrary turn-on/turn-off time"` the only condition to be `a self-commutated switch`?

Can anybody give a definition for this or explain it in detail?

Comment: Physical security information management (PSIM) ?

Comment: No,  it is an electronic circuit simulation software package.

Comment: It's all pretty out of context and meaningless here without more references.

Comment: A self commutated motor, one that you hook up like a regular DC motor, will include such devices internal to it to run the BLDC though.... is that what they are on about?

Comment: @Trevor: I have just added the PSIM part.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=551-16-15) definition..

[image]

So I guess as long as those transistors are not driven from elsewhere you can call them that. However, that really depends on where you define the boundaries of the "convertor or electronic switch"...

Seems rather bizarre to me though, without reading the rest of the PSIM thing's manual for more context.

However since I assume you are talking about [THIS PSIM](https://powersimtech.com/about-us/), which is tailored to power products, motor controllers and the like, then the terminology, though confusing, is more applicable.

> Powersim (PSIM) is specialized in electrical engineering simulation and design tools for research and product development in power supplies, motor drives, power conversion and control systems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Flexible Alternating Current Transmission System (FACTS). One aspect of a FACTS is power electronic switching devices to facilitate the flow of electrical power.

The IEEE definition is:

> a power electronic based system and other static equipment that
>   provide control of one or more AC transmission system parameters to
>   enhance controllability and increase power transfer capability

Power electronics are thus used to facilitate regulation, reliability, improved stability (say harmonic management)

Such VAr compensators can be split into Line-commutating and self-commutating.

**Line commutating**

Line commutating FACTS devices (diodes, thyristors) are slow commutating devices are that usually commutated based upon the phase voltage & are naturally commutation by the increase in forward voltage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_converter#Line-commutated_converters

> Most of the HVDC systems in operation today are based on
>   line-commutated converters (LCC). The term line-commutated indicates
>   that the conversion process relies on the line voltage of the AC
>   system to which the converter is connected in order to effect the
>   commutation from one switching device to its neighbour.[11]
>   Line-commutated converters use switching devices that are either
>   uncontrolled (such as diodes) or that can only be turned on (not off)
>   by control action, such as thyristors. Although HVDC converters can,
>   in principle, be constructed from diodes, such converters can only be
>   used in rectification mode and the lack of controllability of the DC
>   voltage is a serious disadvantage. Consequently, in practice all LCC
>   HVDC systems use either grid-controlled mercury-arc valves (until the
>   1970s) or thyristors (to the present day).

**Self Commutating**

self-commutating FACTS devices on the other hand are higher frequency devices and are capable of injecting voltage or current at the desired point to improve the network characteristics, usually by forced commutation (ie hard switching) and are used in active harmonic scrubbers, active front ends

One example is a Static Synchronous Compensator (STATCOM)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_synchronous_compensator

> A static synchronous compensator (STATCOM), also known as a static
>   synchronous condenser (STATCON), is a regulating device used on
>   alternating current electricity transmission networks. It is based on
>   a power electronics voltage-source converter and can act as either a
>   source or sink of reactive AC power to an electricity network. If
>   connected to a source of power it can also provide active AC power. It
>   is a member of the FACTS family of devices. It is inherently modular
>   and electable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_converter#Voltage-source_converters

Because thyristors can only be turned on (not off) by control action, and rely on the external AC system to effect the turn-off process, the control system only has one degree of freedom – when to turn on the thyristor.[11] This limits the usefulness of HVDC in some circumstances because it means that the AC system to which the HVDC converter is connected must always contain synchronous machines in order to provide the commutating voltage – the HVDC converter cannot feed power into a passive system.

> With some other types of semiconductor device such as the
>   insulated-gate bipolar transistor (IGBT), both turn-on and turn-off
>   can be controlled, giving a second degree of freedom. As a result,
>   IGBTs can be used to make self-commutated converters. In such
>   converters, the polarity of DC voltage is usually fixed and the DC
>   voltage, being smoothed by a large capacitance, can be considered
>   constant. For this reason, an HVDC converter using IGBTs is usually
>   referred to as a voltage-source converter (or voltage-sourced
>   converter[26]).

Answer (score 1):

In this context self-commutated means "can be commutated on or off independently of the load current"

A diode commutates itself depending on the polarity of the current flow, but if the diode is ON, you can't shut it off without changing the direction of the current flow.

An SCR (for a thyristor example) can be turned on with a gate pulse, but can't be shut off until the load current goes below a threshold value near zero.

A BJT, IGBT or FET can be turned on or off at any time, though a FET has a body diode that won't allow shut-off in one direction.

It seems to me to be a poor and confusing descriptor for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Commutation is a term in rectifier/inverter theory taken from DC rotational machines and means transferring the current flowing through the active element to another element (which becomes the next active element). So there is DC current on the output/input.

Self-commutated elements may be shut off anytime, given the current has an alternative path, e.g. through a commutation (freewheeling) diode or another active element.

Non-self-commutated elements cannot be shut off that way, their current has to be brought below their holding current by the AC zero-crossing or, by providing an alternative path with another active element.